# How to specify Access Rules in plugin project dependency outside of Eclipse User Interface

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, emf

I am upgrading a large OSGi project I am working on to work with Java 9 and the latest plug-in libraries. We have to rebuild EMF and package it as a plugin jar. However, some of our code calls an inner class ("EclipsePlugin") that cannot be accessed unless we add an access rule in the project.

It works now, but my question is whether there is a way to do this in the code itself so all of our developers will not have to go in and manually add this rule.

If it is set in the .classpath will Eclipse carry this over when it references the plug-in dependency jar? The way we are packaging EMF it does not include the .classpath files by default. Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this myself by moving the problematic import from "Import-Package:" to "Require-Bundle:" in the MANIFEST.MF file. Apparently this changes the default level of access.